# Update Panel - The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to put an update panel in my aspx form, but it keeps on showing this error. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it

This is my aspx

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <%--<asp:Panel id="pnlExisting" runat="server">
             <div class="alert alert-danger" role="danger">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> <asp:Label ID="recordCheck" runat ="server"> </asp:Label>
             </div>
        </asp:Panel>--%>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Project</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjects" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged" /><br />


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Project Code</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <asp:Textbox ID="txtProjectCode" runat="server" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>




       <%-- <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Price</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <asp:Textbox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" class="form-control" Textmode="Number" required />
            </div>
        </div>--%>

      <%--  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Status</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <asp:Textbox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>--%>


    </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMaterialsList" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lvMaterialsList" EventName="PagePropertiesChanging" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>

                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Date Added</th>
                <th>Date Modified</th>
                <th></th>

            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <asp:ListView ID="lvMaterialsList" runat="server" ondatabound="lvMaterialsList_DataBound" 
                    onpagepropertieschanging="lvMaterialsList_PagePropertiesChanging"  OnItemCommand="lvMaterialsList_ItemCommand">

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>

                            <td><%# Eval("SupplierProduct")%></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DateAdded", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DateModified", "{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}") %></td>

                            <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ltReqMat" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ReqMatID") %>' Visible="false"  />

                                        </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Approved" class="btn btn-success " ID="lbtnApproved" runat="server" 
                                    CommandName="Approve" > </asp:LinkButton> 
                                     <asp:LinkButton Text="Decline" class="btn btn-warning " ID="lbtnDecline" runat="server" 
                                    CommandName="Decline" > </asp:LinkButton>        
                                    </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="12"><h2 class="text-center">No records found.</h2></td>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
               </asp:ListView>
            </tbody>
        </table>
         <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <center>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReturn" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" Text="Back" 
                    PostBackUrl="Default.aspx" formnovalidate />
                    </center>


            </div>

          <br />
                <center>
                    <asp:DataPager ID="dpMaterialsList" runat="server" PageSize="10" PagedControlID="lvMaterialsList">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Button"
                                NumericButtonCssClass="btn btn-default"
                                CurrentPageLabelCssClass="btn btn-success"
                                NextPreviousButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                 </center>
                 </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>


</form>
```

I want to know why it is not working properly

Comment: Where you have placed the `ScriptManager` control on page?

Comment: @RahulSingh Should I put it somewhere in the master page

Comment: You have not included it anywhere on the Master page or content page already?

Comment: Partial postback is a feature of update panel, thus require a script manager, you may refer to the explanation here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169313/what-does-script-manager-control-actually-do

Answer (score 0):

Add `ScriptManager` tags just below the `<Form>` tag of your page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Do comment when you downvote any answer! I find no reason whatsoever here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `ScriptManager` control in either your content page or Master page to enable ASP.NET AJAX features. So in your Master page you can place this control just after the `form` tag and ensure you put it before any `ContentPlaceHolder` control:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

By this all the content page which have the Master page set to the above master will automatically use this `ScriptManager`.

Apart from this, if at all you want to include any specific script reference in any of your content page then you can make use of `ScriptManagerProxy` control which at run time will combine the properties of both `ScriptManager` and `ScriptManagerProxy`.

According to ASP.NET AJAX:-

> **ScriptManager** - A server control that makes script resources available
>   to the browser, including the Microsoft AJAX Library and the
>   functionality that enables partial-page rendering.
>
> **ScriptManagerProxy** - A server control that enables nested components
>   to add script and service references if the page already contains a
>   ScriptManager control.