# inserting a var into Response.Write() string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having trouble adding a variable to a Response.Write() string. When I don't have the var in the string the alert shows correctly. I do know that the var is being populated from the debugger. I also know that the string Concat does return everything with the var value from looking at the locals output in Visual studio. Just don't know why the alert stopped displaying.

```
var savedID = Session["AssignedJobID"];

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Work Request Created.'" + savedID + ");</script>");
```

Comment: Show us the code that is not working (the version with var).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your single quote is in the wrong spot. You need to place it after you write your variable to the response so that the variable's value is included in the js string litteral. Otherwise it is a syntax error.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"<script language='javascript'>alert('Work Request Created. " + {savedID} + "');</script>");
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the 2nd pair of eyes. I figured it had to be something minor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aspnet `ScriptManager` to write javascript to your page insead of Response.Write. It at least places the javascript snippet in the right place instead of at the top of the html.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showAlert", "alert('Work Request Created. " + savedID + "');", true);
```

As to why, read this: [What does script manager control actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169313/what-does-script-manager-control-actually-do)